# on scroll event not binding for dynamically added elements Jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am dynamically adding a `<div>` element with class name `requirement`, what I want to achieve is to execute my functionality when a `scroll` event happens inside of this div.

**HTML**

```
<div class="scroll requirement" >
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on('scroll','.requirement',function(){alert("hello")});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite strange, I guess its because the event can fire so often. It works if it is rebound upon creation...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#add').click(function(){
      $('body').append('<div class="scroll requirement" ><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>');
      $('.requirement').on('scroll',function(){alert("hello")});
    });
 });
```

```css
/*.pane{
    min-height:2000px;
    min-height:400px;
   
}
.requirement{
    max-height:100px;
     overflow:scroll;
}
}*/

  body{ font-family: tahoma; font-size: 12px; }
 div.requirement{
  height: 90px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: lavender;
  overflow: auto;
 }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<div class="scroll requirement" >
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>

<button id="add">Add another pane</button>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Inline binding however works...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#add').click(function(){
      $('body').append('<div class="scroll requirement" onscroll="scrollHandler()" ><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>');
    //  $('.requirement').on('scroll',function(){alert("hello")});
    });

 });
    function scrollHandler(){
    alert('hello');
    }
```

```css
/*.pane{
    min-height:2000px;
    min-height:400px;
   
}
.requirement{
    max-height:100px;
     overflow:scroll;
}
}*/

  body{ font-family: tahoma; font-size: 12px; }
 div.requirement{
  height: 90px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: lavender;
  overflow: auto;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="scroll requirement" onscroll="scrollHandler()" >
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>

<button id="add">Add another pane</button>
  </body>
```

Comment: I am adding  div with class 'requirement' dynamically with ajax post call, it is not working for me, thanks for reply.

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBatta only thing I could find for you is to bind the event inline